# Can't resolve CORS Error in Spring Boot/Angular app

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

Error message:

[image: error]

Security Config has @CrossOrigin

`http.cors(cors->cors.configurationSource(apiConfigurationSource()))`

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource apiConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration=new CorsConfiguration();
          configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","HEADER"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the code.

configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));

Here, you need to specify the url to give instruction to CORS.

configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("http://localhost:4200*"));

I hope this resolves your problem.